# IIS throws 404 when using ImageResizer with S3Reader

Tags: iis-7.5, image-resizing, imageresizer

Normal Imageresizing is working fine, but when using a S3 request, IIS throws me 404 error page as if the virtual path 's3' is unknown. When I directly use the native S3 url, the image is available. I get this error only on production site, not on my local machine.

Gist with the ImageResizer debug output:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5885873

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS and a WebPage in Integrated Mode.

IIS sais:
Module: IIS Web Core
Message: MapRequestHandler
Handler: StaticFile
Errorcode: 0x80070002

Comment: 1. Are files appearing in /imagecache? 2. Does it work if DiskCache is disabled or asyncWrites="true" is set? There's a (small) chance there's a permissions problem.

Comment: No, nothing is saved to the imagecache. Disabling DiskCache does not help. I switched to RemoteReader for now, which works fine. But I would like to use S3Reader in the future.

Comment: What URL are you using?

Comment: Is your S3 bucket in the US? You may need to set the endpoint.